# Cordova getFile error on Android, no error code

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have an app that I am building using Cordova. I need it to work for IOS and Android. I can make it work on IOS, but on Android, no matter what I have done differently, I get the following error object:

```
FileError { code : 'JSON error'}
```

This tells me nothing, I'm not passing it a JSON file, I have no JSON available for it to use other than its options, and those are set correctly. I'm at a loss.

Here is my code for the project:

```
var fileName = "proposal-"+projID+".pdf";
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fs){
    fs.root.getFile(fileName, {create : true, exclusive : false}, function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter){
            fileWriter.onwriteend = function(){
                usSpinnerService.stop("main-spinner");
                cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(fileEntry.nativeURL,"application/pdf",{ 
                    error : function(e) { 
                        console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                    },
                    success : function () {
                        console.log('file opened successfully');                
                    }
                }); 
            };
            fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                console.log("Failed file read: " + e.toString());
            };
            fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, function(err){
            usSpinnerService.stop("main-spinner");
            console.log(err);
        });  
    },
    function(err){
        usSpinnerService.stop("main-spinner");
        console.log(err);
    });
},
function(err){
    usSpinnerService.stop("main-spinner");
    console.log(err);
});
```

I'm doing everything correct, according to their most current documentation, which is found here:

`https://cordova.apache.org/docs/ko/2.0.0/cordova/file/directoryentry/directoryentry.html`

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Updating Cordova File Plugin to the latest version (4.3.1dev) solved the problem as it was most probably caused by faulty code within the plugin itself.

Both `getFile(...)` and `fileWriter.write(...)` returned a "JSON Error" code (which isn't documented) no matter what kind of data and destination path passed.

Using the `FileTransfer` plugin (which relies almost entirely on native code) to create files didn't present any difficulty.